# Display WooCommerce Flat Rate Shipping Options on Cart page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce site and I have a need to display shipping options on the cart page vs the checkout page.

Shipping is flat rate across a single country and not dependent on user location.

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the General tab in Woocommerce Settings.

Set the **shop base address** to be the **Default Customer Location**

If you only have a flat rate and your shop's base address is under it, that's the one that will be displayed by default.

Comment: Got the same issue and this one fixed it, and it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done this

On **Woocommerce** -> **Settings**-> Shipping and make sure that you check the boxes

1. Enable shipping
2. Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page

Save setting and Configure shipping rates as well, hope it will help

Comment: I receive the notice "Shipping costs will be calculated once you have provided your address." with a dropdown asking for country, state, etc